# Customize the message inside MFA

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

When I send a SMS to verify phone number, I receive a text with "data rates may apply.".

The question is, can I remove that or replace all string?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot customize the text of the SMS message. Please raise the [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?category_id=160602) or vote for [similar user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20485813-allow-customization-of-mfa-text-messaging)

Comment: My goal is exclude "data rates may apply" from SMS message, can I achieve that?

Comment: And, Raghavendra, can you inform me when the "data rates may apply" starts appear in SMS message? How I do verify that?

Comment: "MSG & Data rates may apply" disclaimer was added from the first week of October as  some users might be charged for the phone calls or text messages they receive, according to their personal phone service. On of 21st October we dont a customization option and regarding the disclaimer Offical document is yet to be updated

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customise the message, but “data rates may apply.” Is being removed from the sms message in the coming weeks.